# How to get time (hh:mm:ss) from sql query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime, time

I have Database with date field.

I see the time like: `1900-01-01 13:38:00.000`

How i can format it like: `13:38`  ?

Comment: When possible, use SQL for filtering and retrieving data and your client-side code for formatting.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 108)` outputs as `hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: Care you explain your answer or link some documentation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server 2008 then,

Suppose your column name is XTime which is holding time in HH-MM-SS.ms formate. If we want to retrive time in HH-MM-SS format then write following query,

```
Select ID, XDate, Convert(Time(0),XTime,0) -- For HH-MM-SS format
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,'DATE',100),7)
```

For non-military time.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late. This has already been answered by @Yes - That's Jake. It works perfect. But to help you more, I have a cheat sheet link so that you can write it in any format.

You can visit: [Date and Time conversions using SQL cheat sheet](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

You will find a list of codes and the format that @Yes - That's Jake mentioned in his answer.