# How to update datetime field and remove date part from the value in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one column in my Table with DateTime as its datatype.
Now I would like to remove the date part from the datetime column, and update the same column with only time part contained in it. How should I proceed?

Below is the column value :

```
1900-01-01 01:43:00.000
```

Expected value after update would be :

```
01:43:00.000
```

Comment: This question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449552/how-to-get-time-hhmmss-from-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

If you use SQL Server from version 2008 onwards you can use

```
SELECT CAST('1900-01-01 01:43:00.000' as TIME)
```

For earlier versions, use

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),'1900-01-01 01:43:00.000',108)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query for getting time from datetime format.

**select cast(yourdatetimecol as time) [time]**
from yourtable